# unable to load a module from a python package despite it is present

Tags: python

mohkum03@login4 /arm/projectscratch/pd/pr420_AArchv8/users/mohkum03/aarchmrs-db % **python** .submodules/sysreg-tools/scripts/generate_index_files.py --source=output/xml/ --aarch32_sysindex=AArch32-sysindex.xml --aarch32_regindex=AArch32-regindex.xml --aarch64_sysindex=AArch64-sysindex.xml --aarch64_regindex=AArch64-regindex.xml --ext_alpha_index=ext_alpha_index.xml --encoding_index=enc_index.xml --func_group_index=func_index.xml --component_group_index=ext_enc_index.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):

****File ".submodules/sysreg-tools/scripts/generate_index_files.py", line 2, in 
from summarizer.xml_summarizer import XMLSummarizer
ImportError: No module named summarizer.xml_summarizer****

*Don't Know why, not able to load this module even if it is there in ./submodules/sysreg-tools/summarizer*

Comment: Did you include \_\_init\_\_.py file in the module?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that u need to install or upgrade it , see the link below it maybe help you to upgrade the summarizer
https://github.com/dmmiller612/bert-extractive-summarizer/issues/30

they used `pip install --upgrade bert-extractive-summarizer` to upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the package worked for me.

```
pip install --upgrade bert-extractive-summarizer
```